# Domain specific plotting using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm doing several domain specific plots using an excel template that looks like these [image].

My initial idea was to start with a blank plot and then add several segments and lines. But that appears not to be working well for me and taking much time to figure out. I was wondering if anyone has suggestion on how to accomplish this faster.

The plots types often changes too, not just this two types

I've seen this posts and they're different problems

1. [Multiple Curves With Different Domains in a Single Plot ( with ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928293/multiple-curves-with-different-domains-in-a-single-plot-with-ggplot2)
2. [Limit the domain of a custom function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898516/limit-the-domain-of-a-custom-function-in-r).

However, its somewhat similar to [Reproduce a plot using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65772157/reproduce-a-plot-using-ggplot). But my plots are more complex because like "B" in the image shared, they can have 4 axis.

Comment: Can you share your data? (If your excel template is transforming the input data in some way, ideally both the raw and transformed data?)

Comment: @zephryl ... the excel doesn't do any transformation we simply plot to see whether our data falls within some segments or not. So having a generic plotting base is the main purpose of my post ....  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s an attempt at the top panel:

```
set.seed(13)
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

xy_max <- 45

template_specs <- data.frame(
  seg_x = seq(5, xy_max, by = 10),
  seg_y = c(8, 21, 31, 39, 45), 
  seg_lab = seq(40, 0, by = -10)
)

template <- ggplot(template_specs) +
  geom_textsegment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = seg_x, y = seg_y, yend = 0, label = seg_lab),
    offset = unit(-.75, "line"),
    hjust = .45,
    gap = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_textsegment(
    x = 0, xend = xy_max, y = xy_max, yend = 0, 
    label = "Intergranular Porosity (%)",
    text_only = TRUE,
    offset = unit(.75, "line"),
    hjust = .25
  ) +
  geom_segment(x = 0, y = 0, xend = xy_max/2, yend = xy_max/2) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "CEPL (%)",
    breaks = 0:9*5,
    expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "COPL (%)",
    breaks = 0:9*5,
    expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8),
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )

template
```

[image]

```
example_data <- data.frame(
  section = paste("Section", rep(LETTERS[1:8], 8)),
  x = abs(rnorm(64, 0, 2)),
  y = rnorm(64, 27.5, 7)
)

template +
  geom_point(
    data = example_data,
    aes(x = x, y = y, color = section),
    shape = 18,
    size = 3
  )
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU ... seems the second panel will be impossible

Comment: @Hammao, it should be possible by adapting the code for the first panel and adding secondary axes.  Look into the `sec.axis` argument to `scale_x_continuous()` / `scale_y_continuous()`.